# Перемещение строки таблицы из точки "а" в "б", используя анимацию jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Здравствуйте! На изображении предложен небольшой шаблон. Таблица в поле слева от таблицы в поле справа отличается на одну строку. Левое поле обозначает то, что было, правое, то что стало. Необходимо в левой таблице выделить цветом место, где будет добавлена новая строка, затем на этом месте добавить строку и плавно переместить ее в правую таблицу.

```
<div class="control">
    <div class="prev_iter">
        <div class="truthTable">
            <table class="TT"> 
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="bit" style="border: none"> </th>
                    <th class="bit" style="background-color: #87D37C">x<sub>2</sub></th>
                    <th class="bit" style="background-color: #87D37C">x<sub>1</sub></th>
                    <th class="bit" style="background-color: #87D37C">x<sub>0</sub></th>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="current_iter">
        <div class="truthTable">
            <table class="TT"> 
                <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <th class="bit" style="border: none"> </th>
                    <th class="bit" style="background-color: #87D37C">x<sub>2</sub></th>
                    <th class="bit" style="background-color: #87D37C">x<sub>1</sub></th>
                    <th class="bit" style="background-color: #87D37C">x<sub>0</sub></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="bit" style="border: none">0: </td>
                    <td class="bit">0</td>
                    <td class="bit">0</td>
                    <td class="bit">0</td>
                </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>  
    <br>
    <div class="controlButtons">    
        <input id="back" name="back" onclick="controllerSwitchSteps(this.id);" type="button" value="&lt;Назад">
        Шаг <span id="stepNumber">2</span> из <span id="totalSteps">13</span>
        <input id="next" name="next" onclick="controllerSwitchSteps(this.id);" type="button" value="Вперед&gt;">    
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]